# best way to represent a bidirectional traversable hierarchy

Tags: python, parent, parent-child, hierarchy

I need to represent some data as a hierarchy where an object can have one parent and many children. I also need to be able to get a child's parent in the same way that i would a child.

I tried this

```
class Root():
    def __init__(self):
        self.child = Node(self)

class Node():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
```

Is there a common way of solving this problem out there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that this is basically how `Tkinter` does it:

```
class Root(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []

class Node(object):
   def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent = parent
        parent.children.append(self)
```

Now, `Root` knows all it's children via the `children` attribute, and the children know their parents via the `parent` attribute.

```
r = Root()
n = Node(r)
r.children[0] is n  #True
n.parent is r  #True
```

Of course, you could make things a little more interesting by giving `Node` objects a `children` attribute as well -- Then `Node`s can parent more `Node`s.  Neat.

There are some downsides here (mainly cyclic references).  If you want to avoid that, you could use `weakref.ref`s to store the references to the children/parents, but I'll defer that to another question if necessary.

Comment: This is how I would do it, too.  The cyclic references can be a problem if you're programmatically traversing the tree in a recursive subroutine, but there's ways around that (path tracing is a brute-force option for such a thing).  One advantage to being able to look back up the tree, however, is the ability to have a child.path() method that returns the path from the root to that node.

Comment: Also, you could do this without a Root object.  If you just use the Node objects and pass in None for the parent parameter of your root Node object, that should achieve the same effect.

Comment: @Adrian -- Yep.  I only kept a `Root` object because the OP did.  But you're right, having a `Root` object is unnecessary if `Node` has both `children` and `parent` attributes.